# MySQL database with user created tables with custom column numbers

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a person table and I want users to be able to create custom many to many relations of information with them. Educations, residences, employments, languages, and so on. These might require different number of columns. E.g.

```
Person_languages(person_fk,language_fk)
Person_Educations(person,institution,degree,field,start,end)
```

I thought of something like this. (Not correct sql)

```
create Tables(
             table_id PRIMARY_KEY,
             table_name_fk FOREIGN_KEY(Table_name),
             person_fk FOREIGN_KEY(Person),
             table_description TEXT
            )
```

Table holding all custom table name and descriptions

```
create Table_columns(
                     column_id PRIMARY_KEY,
                     table_fk FOREIGN_KEY(Tables),
                     column_name_fk FOREIGN_KEY(Columns),
                     rank_column INT,
                    )
```

Table holding the columns in each custom table and the order they are to be displayed in.

```
create Table_rows(
                  row_id PRIMARY_KEY,
                  table_fk FOREIGN_KEY(Tables),
                  row_nr INT,
                 )
```

Table holding the rows of each custom table.

```
create Table_cells(
                   cell_id PRIMARY_KEY,
                   table_fk FOREIGN_KEY(Tables),
                   row_fk FOREIGN_KEY(Table_rows),
                   column_fk FOREIGN_KEY(Table_columns),
                   cell_content_type_fk FOREIGN_KEY(Content_types),
                   cell_object_id INT,
                  )
```

Table holding cell info.

If any custom table starts to be used with most persons and becomes large, the idea was to maybe then extract it into a separate hard-coded many-to-many table just for that table.

Is this a stupid idea? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advise against such a design - you are on the road to an extremely fragmented and hard to read design.

IIUC your base problem is, that you have a common set of (universal) properties for a person, that may be extended by other (non-universal) properties.

I'd tackle this by having the universal properties in the person table and create two more tables: `property_types`, which translates a property name into an `INT` primary key and `person_properties` which combines person PK, propety PK and value.

If you set the PK of this table to be `(person,property)` you get the best possible index locality for the person, which makes requesting all properties for a person a very fast query.

Comment: +1 And here's an instructional tale: http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/